# PDF background color other than white: is it acceptable for formal documents?

Tags: color, typography

In LaTeX, one can change the background color of the whole document easily through the `pagecolor` package. I was experimenting with it and I've found that setting the background color to be slightly darker than white makes the page look better, "more organic", in my opinion.

[image: before]
[image: after]

My question is, is this acceptable in formal documents (say, an invoice or a contract), or is it better to stick with the pure white?

Comment: I would sign an increase in payment contract even on red paper ... ;-) But I think it's established: white paper is the 'norm'

Comment: It costs 27 times more to print. Consider getting "organic" paper instead.

Comment: I don't think it's very ecofriendly... maybe you shuld just buy some kind of recycled paper that is less white...

Comment: Ok, I should have specified: I start from the assumption (probably wrong) that the document will not be printed. Also, maybe there's a way to ignore the background color in the printer settings? (I don't own a printer so I can't check if this is the case, but sounds plausible to me)

Answer (score 6):

Imho you shouldn't assume that people don't print a pdf and so \pagecolor is not really an option. But you can a similar effect with layers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,color}
\geometry{papersize={4cm, 4cm}} %for the tests
\usepackage{ocg-p,tikz,eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG
{\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{backgroundcolor}{oc1}{1}
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\fill[red](current page.north east)rectangle (current page.south west);
 \end{ocg}}
\begin{document}
Blabla
\newpage
Blabla

\end{document}
```

Comment: And how does that solve the issue with the printing? Layers don't get printed?

Comment: Well make an educated guess what `printocg=never` does -- or look in the documentation of `ocg-p`.

Comment: One might add that this only works when printed from an application that understands OCGs (ie., only with Acrobat).

Comment: @Robert: I tried with sumatra too and it worked.

Comment: Interesting, does sumatra support OCG now, or only the print state? Anyway, just for the record, I tried with Preview, and the background was printed.

Comment: +1: That is perfect! Works as advertised :). I assume that `eso-pic` is not needed here?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner but today I would suggest to use ocgx2 and not ocg-p.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no if there is a chance people will print the document, it'll come out terribly and drain their cartridges.