# changing background color of a letter template

Tags: color, backgrounds, letters, overleaf

I found the `tuletter` class in Overleaf (which loads the `article` class) and I've been using it for typing letters of correspondence. Now, I want to change the background color of the letter from the default white to another color, say yellow.

To do this, I use `\pagecolor{yellow}` from the `xcolor` package. However, the header text/elements can't be seen if this is done (see image below).

[image: before and after using <code>\pagecolor{yellow}</code>]

I've also used the following code from an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276532/pdf-background-color-other-than-white-is-it-acceptable-for-formal-documents/276554#276554) but the same thing happens as when `\pagecolor{yellow}` is used.:

> `\usepackage{ocg-p,tikz,eso-pic}
>       \AddToShipoutPictureBG
>       {\begin{ocg}[printocg=never]{backgroundcolor}{oc1}{1}
>         \tikz[overlay,remember picture]\fill[red](current page.north east)rectangle (current page.south west);
>        \end{ocg}}`

My question is how does one change the background color of a letter (preferably `tuletter` class) such that the header elements can be seen?

EDIT: Here is the MWE of the main texfile `tuletter_en.tex` (coming from the [Overleaf template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tu-delft-letter/rzbjtdrxhbtx)) and which I edit on Overleaf:

```
\documentclass[en]{tuletter} 
% this package is only needed for demo (\lipsum)
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{times} %Times New Roman Font

\usepackage{xcolor}

% Signature at the end of the letter are used with \closing
\signname{J. Doe}
\signimage{signature_jdoe} % pjansen is the filename of the image of the signature (i.e. 'pjansen.png')
% if needed a second signature can be given with \signnamesec and \signimagesec

% Reference top left
\date{\today}
\ourref{UP001}
\yourref{IP1001}
\contact{Contact Person}
\phone{015-278 0000}
\email{c.person@tudelft.nl}
\subject{TU Delft Formal Letter}

% Recipient left under reference
\toname{R.E. Ceiver}
\toaddress{Here and there 22\\4242 AA Hurdieburdie}

% Sender right under logo
\fromname{Faculty of \ldots}
\fromaddress{There 3\\2628 AA Delft}
\frompobox{504\\2600 AA Delft}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\makeheader
\opening{Dear Sir/Madam,}
% show two paragraphs of text
\lipsum[1-2]
\closing{With kind regards,}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output of the MWE:

[image: output of MWE]

I've tried looking at tuletter.cls but my limited TeX/LaTeX knowledge can't seem to grok it.

Comment: You have to provide a complete MWE. I changed page colour to yellow for one of my documents, and headers and footers showed up just fine.

Comment: This worked: `\documentclass{scrlttr2}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \pagecolor{lightgray}`

Answer (score 3):

Textblocks from the header in the class file are not being shown. Textblocks are coming from the textpos package. Add overlay to the options:

```
\RequirePackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
```

I created a project with the solution here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/yyvxwgyyrjns

[image]